# Removing indexes of master database from Content delivery log files

Tags: indexing, sitecore

I want to remove the indexing of master database from content delivery log files.I added SwitchMasterToWeb.config to the app_config/include folder but still I am getting indexing of master databases in my log files.

Is there any configuration required or I need to customize some Sitecore files?

Comment: Do you see any instances of the word 'master' when you load up ShowConfig.aspx on your CD?

Comment: @JayS Yes, there are lot of references to "master" database.

Comment: @Babita according to Stack Overflow etiquette, you should always try to choose an answer and mark it as accepted. Do this for whatever answer worked best for you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the `master` index from your content delivery server to remove log files.
In a Sitecore 7.2 solution, in my SwitchMasterToWeb.config file I have the following patch:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:set="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/set/">
  <sitecore>
    <search>
      <configuration>
        <indexes>
          <index>
            <locations>
              <master>
                <patch:delete />
              </master>
            </locations>
          </index>
        </indexes>
      </configuration>
    </search>

    <contentSearch>
      <indexUpdateStrategies>
        <intervalAsyncCore type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Maintenance.Strategies.IntervalAsynchronousStrategy, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
          <patch:delete/>
        </intervalAsyncCore>
        <intervalAsyncMaster type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Maintenance.Strategies.IntervalAsynchronousStrategy, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
          <patch:delete/>
        </intervalAsyncMaster>
        <syncMaster type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Maintenance.Strategies.SynchronousStrategy, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
          <param desc="database">web</param>
        </syncMaster>
      </indexUpdateStrategies>
    </contentSearch>
    <!-- other patching configurations -->
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I have used Sitecore 8 SwitchMasterToWeb.config file to app_config/include folder from http://gist.github.com/kamsar/8096336f141c0e5e97b3  but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Yeh Kamsar file is almost same thing like my file. I guess you have some small errors in your configurations that's why is not working fine.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you saw the exception `Message: Index sitecore_master_index was not found` in your log files on Content Delivery Server. It is a know issue for Sitecore and you will need to install a support package, based on your Sitecore version which are listed on the [Sitecore Knowledge Base](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/398869)

Comment: I am not getting an exception that you have mentioned in my log files.Then I renamed the file SwitchMasterToWeb.config to zSwitchMasterToWeb.config so that it is applied at the end but still I am not getting an exception in my log files. Do I need to give any references of this config file?

Answer (score 1):

If you are still seeing references to the master database after applying the SwitchmasterToWeb it is possible that either the file is not being loaded correctly or is loading too early.

I try to put it in a sub-folder that will process last (such as App_Config\Include\zzz_FinalConfigs). That way I can be sure it runs after all of the Sitecore subfolders and configuration files.

At this point, load up ShowConfig.aspx and verify that all references to the master database have been removed. You can look for patch:source references to your switchmastertoweb.config file to see if your file is being read and parsed.

If not, you may be editing the wrong file system.